# Adding Totals for each column in table/Matrix with two row groups and a column group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table/matrix with 3 groups, 1 column group and 2 rows groups. [image]

I need to add a row at the bottom that will display totals on each column. I have tried working with the "right-click > Add Total" thingy but it only adds the static column "Total" but the grouped columns are blank; there's no expression.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Drag and drop your measure on the textboxes, it will create sum expressions

Answer (score 0):

Your current design appears to have no numeric data to summarise, so when you add a total row, SSRS does not know what or how you want your aggregation to work.

You can manually add expressions to the textboxes total line, so if you wanted a count of results you could use something like.

```
=COUNT(Fields!AnswerText.Value)
```

If this does not help, explain what you want to see on your total row and how you would calculate it.

Comment: AnswerText is the numeric field. I have tried SUM(Fields!AnswerText.Value) but that gives #Error. The 'totals' row must display the sum for each column (Top to bottom)

Comment: Is AnswerText actually a numeric field or a text field containing numbers as strings? if it's actually text then try `=SUM(CInt(Fields!AnswerText.Value))`